# Best practice for terminating C++ programs with many custom error messages

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have a code with a lot of "sanity checks" for many different user errors that cannot be easily classified or grouped into categories/exceptions. I find myself writing a lot of code like the example below, where I initialise a result variable, check for possible errors and either calculate the result or exit the program. I think this is better than `if (x > 0) { return x; } else { terminate_with_error(...); };`, but I was wondering if there is a neater way to set this up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void terminate_with_error(std::string err_string) {
  std::cerr << err_string << std::endl;
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

double stay_positive(double x) {
  double result;
  if (x < 0) {
    terminate_with_error("Don't be so negative!");
  } else {
    result = x;
  };
  return result;
}

int main() {
  stay_positive(-1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are looking for. did you consider exceptions?

Comment: From your description they all belong to "sanity checks" group.

Comment: The sources of errors are quite diverse and I want to include very informative text, so exceptions didn't seem that appropriate. It's just that the pattern above is very repetitive and having to initialise things like ```double result``` just because I don't want the return statement in the if clause seems unnecessary, too. I just want to reduce the number of lines of code to write. Maybe that's bad micro optimisation...

Comment: Why do you think you cannot have informative text with exceptions? it is actually quite the opposite: `throw std::invalid_argument("X Cannot be negative")` is very descriptive, not just in the error, but also in the type of exception.

Comment: *"sources of errors are quite diverse and I want to include very informative text, so exceptions didn't seem that appropriate"* Why not? If you don't want to create tons of exception classes, throw `std::runtime_error`.

Comment: "The sources of errors are quite diverse and I want to include very informative text," no argument against exceptions. You can define various custom exceptions with as much descriptive text you want. If thats the only reason not to use exceptions the answer is: use exceptions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding on the usefulness of exception. I'll just refer you to this [FAQ: Exceptions and Error handling](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#why-exceptions) and only adress this part of the quesiton:

> It's just that the pattern above is very repetitive and having to initialise things like double result just because I don't want the return statement in the if clause seems unnecessary, too. I just want to reduce the number of lines of code to write.

You do not have to do any of that.

```
double stay_positive(double x) {
  double result;
  if (x < 0) {
    terminate_with_error("Don't be so negative!");
  } else {
    result = x;
  };
  return result;
}
```

Frankly, this function is really verbose and longwinded. Most of it can be removed:

```
double stay_positive(double x) {
  if (x < 0) terminate_with_error("Don't be so negative!");
  return x;
}
```

For convenience you can turn your `terminate_with_error` into a `terminate_if(bool,std::string)` such that you can write

```
double stay_positive(double x) {
  terminate_if(x<0,"Don't be so negative!");
  return x;
}
```

However, calling `exit` already when the problem occurs is extremely unflexible on the long run. What if you have a situation where `x<0` is an error, but one you can recover from? In such case the function should only signal to the caller that there was a problem and let the caller decide how to proceed. You do not have to reinvent a wheel for that, because there are exceptions. If you write this:

```
double stay_positive(double x) {
  if (x<0) throw "x must be positive";
  return x;
}
```

the caller can decide to catch the exception and try to recover from the error (of course the exception should contain more inforamtion than just a string, eg the value of `x`), or not catch it which will eventually cause a termination of the program.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed advice and the useful link! It's exactly the type of simplification that what I was looking for, despite it probably being embarrassingly straight-forward for most on here.